# How can I Unescape and Reescape strings in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping

I need a TextBox on a WPF control that can take in text like `Commit\r\n\r` (which is the .net string `"Commit\\r\\n\\r"`) and convert it back to `"Commit\r\n\r"` as a .net string.  I was hoping for a string.Unescape() and string.Escape() method pair, but it doesn't seem to exist.  Am I going to have to write my own? or is there a more simple way to do this?

Comment: Don't type that in the text box, just press the Enter key.

Comment: and if they want to say \r\n\r\r? (yes, this is a viable situation on this particular model)

Comment: Check this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/08bb20a2-82b9-4f2f-9f1a-994961fbecc3/

Comment: @Hans: good answer, please elaborate for other readers, convert to C#, and post again and I will select it as an answer.

Comment: @firoso: Why don't *you* do it?

Comment: @silky : I didn't provide the solution, Hans deserves the Rep.

Answer (score 44):

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(@"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHello world!")
```

[Regex.Unescape method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

Comment: System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape()

Comment: Beware that this is `Regex` specific and also escapes strings like `@"\["` into `@"["` which is only desired if we are talking about a regex, not a normal string.

Answer (score 10):

Hans's code, improved version.

1. Made it use StringBuilder - a real performance booster on long strings
2. Made it an extension method

   ```
   public static class StringUnescape
   {
       public static string Unescape(this string txt)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt)) { return txt; }
           StringBuilder retval = new StringBuilder(txt.Length);
           for (int ix = 0; ix < txt.Length; )
           {
               int jx = txt.IndexOf('\\', ix);
               if (jx < 0 || jx == txt.Length - 1) jx = txt.Length;
               retval.Append(txt, ix, jx - ix);
               if (jx >= txt.Length) break;
               switch (txt[jx + 1])
               {
                   case 'n': retval.Append('\n'); break;  // Line feed
                   case 'r': retval.Append('\r'); break;  // Carriage return
                   case 't': retval.Append('\t'); break;  // Tab
                   case '\\': retval.Append('\\'); break; // Don't escape
                   default:                                 // Unrecognized, copy as-is
                       retval.Append('\\').Append(txt[jx + 1]); break;
               }
               ix = jx + 2;
           }
           return retval.ToString();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: FYI the listed function has the wrong name - it is /unescaping/ a string, but is called EscapeStringChars().

Comment: This seems to work better than other answers, but still doesn't support all C# escape sequences: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#unicode-character-escape-sequences

Answer (score 4):

Following methods are same as javascript escape/unescape functions:

```
Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.unescape();

Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.escape();
```