# Evaluate escaped string

Tags: c#, string

I have some strings in a file that are already escaped. So the content of the file looks like this:

```
Hello\nWorld. This is\tGreat.
```

When I read the file, I get `\n` as two different characters instead of one.

How can I convert an escaped string to a non-escaped one?

Comment: Can it contain anything C# string literal can contain, like Unicode escape sequences? What about quotation marks?

Answer (score 8):

based on @deAtog 's code, i made some minor additions

- support \U00000000 format chars
- simplify the hex conversions somewhat

  ```
  string UnEscape(string s)
  {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      Regex r = new Regex("\\\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\\\]|\\\\[0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}|\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\\\U[0-9a-fA-F]{8}|.");
      MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s, 0);

      foreach (Match m in mc)
      {
          if (m.Length == 1)
          {
              sb.Append(m.Value);
          }
          else
          {
              if (m.Value[1] >= '0' && m.Value[1] <= '7')
              {
                  int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.Substring(1), 8);
                  sb.Append((char)i);
              }
              else if (m.Value[1] == 'u')
              {
                  int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.Substring(2), 16);
                  sb.Append((char)i);
              }
              else if (m.Value[1] == 'U')
              {
                  int i = Convert.ToInt32(m.Value.Substring(2), 16);
                  sb.Append(char.ConvertFromUtf32(i));
              }
              else
              {
                  switch (m.Value[1])
                  {
                      case 'a':
                          sb.Append('\a');
                          break;
                      case 'b':
                          sb.Append('\b');
                          break;
                      case 'f':
                          sb.Append('\f');
                          break;
                      case 'n':
                          sb.Append('\n');
                          break;
                      case 'r':
                          sb.Append('\r');
                          break;
                      case 't':
                          sb.Append('\t');
                          break;
                      case 'v':
                          sb.Append('\v');
                          break;
                      default:
                          sb.Append(m.Value[1]);
                          break;
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      return sb.ToString();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx).

There's also an entry on the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/08bb20a2-82b9-4f2f-9f1a-994961fbecc3/).

*See also [How can I Unescape and Reescape strings in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net) .*

Comment: Quick correction: that's `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape`. Please revise.

Comment: `Regex.Unescape` is unapplicable here, it is used to unescape regex control characters only.

Answer (score 3):

Like you I was unable to find a decent solution to this problem. While you can certainly use String.Replace, the performance and speed of this solution is terrible. Furthermore, it's hard to support octal and Unicode escape sequences via this method. A much better alternative is to use a simple RegEx parser. Here's a method that will properly un-escape any string given. It supports standard escape sequences, octal escape sequences, and unicode escape sequences.

```
string UnEscape(string s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Regex r = new Regex("\\\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\\\]|\\\\[0-3]?[0-7]{1,2}|\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|.");
    MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s, 0);

    foreach (Match m in mc) {
        if (m.Length == 1) {
            sb.Append(m.Value);
        } else {
            if (m.Value[1] >= '0' && m.Value[1] <= '7') {
                int i = 0;

                for (int j = 1; j < m.Length; j++) {
                    i *= 8;
                    i += m.Value[j] - '0';
                }

                sb.Append((char)i);
            } else if (m.Value[1] == 'u') {
                int i = 0;

                for (int j = 2; j < m.Length; j++) {
                    i *= 16;

                    if (m.Value[j] >= '0' && m.Value[j] <= '9') {
                        i += m.Value[j] - '0';
                    } else if (m.Value[j] >= 'A' && m.Value[j] <= 'F') {
                        i += m.Value[j] - 'A' + 10;
                    } else if (m.Value[j] >= 'a' && m.Value[j] <= 'f') {
                        i += m.Value[j] - 'a' + 10;
                    }
                }

                sb.Append((char)i);
            } else {
                switch (m.Value[1]) {
                    case 'a':
                        sb.Append('\a');
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        sb.Append('\b');
                        break;
                    case 'f':
                        sb.Append('\f');
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        sb.Append('\n');
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        sb.Append('\r');
                        break;
                    case 't':
                        sb.Append('\t');
                        break;
                    case 'v':
                        sb.Append('\v');
                        break;
                    default:
                        sb.Append(m.Value[1]);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was great, i made some minor improvements to support \U00000000 format chars and simplify the hex conversions somewhat.  I have submitted my version below but feel free to incorporate it into yours instead.

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like:

```
string str = str.Replace(@"\n","\n");
```

#### update:

Obviously this is a workaround as the scenario is "un natural" by itself. The `Regex.Unescape` solution is unapplicable here as it is intended to use for unescaping regex control characters, and not new lines etc.

In order to support other relevant characters one can write a replacing function like this one:

```
public string ReEscapeControlCharacters(string str) {
   return str.Replace(@"\n","\n").Replace(@"\r","\r").Replace(@"\t","\t");
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround. What about \t and the others hidden and control characters? Should he do it for all others?

Comment: Obviously it is a workaround... I am updating the answer with further detail

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
String replaced = startstring.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, desirevalue);
```

This have to be valid only for "\n".

Comment: That would be if it was an interpreted `\n`, not an _escaped_ literal "slash-enn".