# How to prevent C# from escaping my string?

Tags: c#, escaping

I have Windows Forms UI, that allows me to enter format for string formatting in TextBox, like:

Enter result format: `{sku}:{value} \n`

Problem is, that \n is getting escaped, so result format string in debug view looks like:

```
{sku}:{value} \\n
```

And that produces \n instead of line break in result.

So question is, how to prevent this, or how to remove escaping before using in `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`

Update: I've decided to add image from notepad++ window, may be that will help understand what I need and why (although my use case is a bit different, I think idea is the same):
[image]

Comment: That's just a debugger display artifact, it is not the language doing this.  A \n is only valid in literals in your code, parsed by the compiler.  You cannot type it into, say, the Properties window.  Or a TextBox, you'd need to set Multiline = true and press the Enter key.

Comment: The debug view is displaying the string escaped, but I think you'll find that the string doesn't actually contain the escape. Output the string to a MessageBox and see if the escape is really there.

Comment: Did you try to do "{sku}:{value}" + '\n'.ToString(), had an simmilar issue, where it worked to use an "char" instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, Jim: If it is debugger display artifact, why after using StringBuilder.AppendFormat(textbox.Text, args) i see \n instead of new lines?

Comment: The debugger shows you the string the way you'd write it in your source code.  Click the magnifier icon to bring up the text visualizer.  It shows you how it looks on the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably, what you want to do is to use the string.Replace(@"\n", "\n") method. View more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx

Comment: +1 yup - because when you create a string from input (say from a textbox) like `"\n"` that's the exact string that's getting created & which means nothing special to the string at runtime.  Whereas the escape `\n` in a C# code file is an instruction to the compiler to emit a newline (character code 13 in decimal).

Comment: Would be nice to have generic approach, to handle \t and etc, but if there will be none, will accept as an answer.

Comment: @Giedrus you can't really (unless you do something nasty like invoke the C# compiler to compile a string literal from the input and then grab it back) because you're effectively creating your own language and therefore have to parse it and translate it.  The escape sequences we know and love are C#-related, not .Net related.

Comment: Well, there aren't that many of them, see [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/cf2e3220-dc8d-4de7-96d3-44dd93a52423), so it's an easy task checking all of them in a method

Comment: I totally agree; and yes a simple solution is more than achievable - I was just responding to what appeared to me to be a belief from @Giedrius that escape sequences are somehow embedded in the framework, which they're not.  A simple map of symbols and replacements will work perfectly here.

Answer (score 4):

There is a general way of doing the unescaping of the string is to use regular expression

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(yourStringVariable);
```

[How can I Unescape and Reescape strings in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much, this is what a was search for