# Unescaping strings in c# using string.Replace?

Tags: c#, escaping

I have a collection of strings within a checkListBox and I convert this collection into a `List<string>`. During this conversion I can only imagine the strings are escaped due to them being in the below format:

```
<category title="FOO">
```

This then becomes

```
"<category title=\"FOO\">
```

I need to unescape these strings for comparison, and I've tried something like

```
 s.Replace(@"\""", @""""); <-------- trying to replace all \" with "
```

Is this even possible? And if so what's the correct way of removing slashes from quotes in a string?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [Unescape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape.aspx)

```
    var str = "<category title=\"FOO\">";
    var result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(str);
    Console.WriteLine(result); //<category title="FOO">

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: this does not work on double quote character "

Comment: this does not work, I want to call ffmpeg.exe which see stupid microsoft weird conventions \"c:\\path\\file.txt\"

Comment: Agree with @Aaron this doesnt work `\""[` is still the same after `Regex.Unescape(` I just tried right now

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex.Unescape Method to resolve.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx

Or you can use Uri.UnescapeDataString Method.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661169/how-can-i-unescape-and-reescape-strings-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Try Replace("\\"", "\""), or even better Replace("\", "")

Comment: Just realised that the string doesn't contain a closing tag, so your second suggestion would work providing the slash doesn't interfere with the second quote (which it does unfortunately)

Comment: `Replace("\"", "");` this worked