# How to send a json into IoT Hub without the '\' character

Tags: c#, json, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to send a JSON string into Azure IoT Hub with the following format:

`string format = "{\"info1\":\"info1Data\",\"info2\":\"info2Data\",\"info3\":{\"info3Data\":[]}}";`

The problem is that after I serialize the string into a JSON Object it sends this to the IoT Hub :

{\"info1\":\"info1Data\",\"info2\":\"info2Data\",\"info3\":{\"info3Data\":[]}}

My goal is to remove the '\' character from the string sent to the IoT, and with that goal i tried several ways to work around this problem , such as :

```
 var test= new string(format.ToCharArray());
 test.Trim();
 Console.WriteLine(test);
 testing = test.Replace(@"\", "");
 Console.WriteLine(testing);
```

OR

```
var charsToRemove = new string[] { @"\" };
 foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
 {
    testing = testing.Replace(c, string.Empty);
 }
 Console.WriteLine(testing);
```

I'm using VS2019 and I still can't remove the '\' char from the string.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37884275/3075190

Comment: How do you know this is sent? If you got this from the debugger, ignore it as the debugger will insert the escaping characters although they aren't present in the actual strings.

Comment: Where are you serializing the object?

Comment: @ckuri I am confirming trough Device Explorer Twin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type, for instance:

```
var data = new { info1 = "info1Data", info2 = "info2Data", info3 = new { info3Data = new JArray() } };
var jsontext = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsontext));
await client.SendEventAsync(message);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, i manage to get it to work with the format i had before. Thanks . 

My next concern will be how to insert data in the JArray, but as far as the question goes it is solved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the quotes by doubling them ("") in a raw string (@) as explained in the following post:

[How to add double quotes to a string that is inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905946/how-to-add-double-quotes-to-a-string-that-is-inside-a-variable)

**For your example:**

```
string format = @"{""info1"":""info1Data"",""info2"":""info2Data"",""info3"":""info3Data"":[]}}";
```

Comment: First of all i would like to thank you for the fast response, however i'm still facing dificulties, and with the goal to clarify what exactly i'm doing i will post all the code regarding this issue bellow .


 `string format = @"{""info1"":""info1Data"",""info2"":""info2Data"",""info3"":""info3Data"":[]}}";`
`var messageString1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(format);`
`var message1 = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString1));`
`var json1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(format);`
`client.SendEventAsync(message1);`

Comment: and i'm still getting the following result in IoT Hub :{\"info1\":\"info1Data\",\"info2\":\"info2Data\",\"info3\":\"info3Data\":[]}}

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject accepts an object, you are passing a string object.. try to use a dynamic object: https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/c-dynamic-object-and-json-serialization-with-json-net/

Comment: Something like: dynamic foo = new ExpandoObject();

foo.info1 = "info1Data";
foo.info2 = "info2Data";
...

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo)